# Java insertion sorting: "same" variable get different result

Tags: java, algorithm

I was doing an insertion sort using Java.
For example, if I have an integer array {8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1},

This will give me the result which is wrong: 7,6,5,4,3,2,1,8 [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4j45.jpg)

```
public static int[] insertionSort(int[] list) {
    int[] insertionList = list.clone();
    for(int i = 1; i < insertionList.length; i++) {
        int temp = insertionList[i];
        int j = i - 1;
        while(j >= 0 && insertionList[j] > insertionList[i]) {
            insertionList[j + 1] = insertionList[j];
            j--;
        }
        insertionList[j + 1] = temp;
    }
    return insertionList;
}
```

And this will give me the result which I wanted: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKVaH.jpg)

```
public static int[] insertionSort(int[] list) {
    int[] insertionList = list.clone();
    for(int i = 1; i < insertionList.length; i++) {
        int temp = insertionList[i];
        int j = i - 1;
        while(j >= 0 && insertionList[j] > temp) {
            insertionList[j + 1] = insertionList[j];
            j--;
        }
        insertionList[j + 1] = temp;
    }
    return insertionList;
}
```

Just wondering what different between `insertionList[i]` and `temp`. I wrote two `println` statements to test these, but they also show the same number.

Thanks!!!!!

Comment: Please paste the required code here itself.

Comment: You should add your code in the post also. By the way, the first version of insertion sort seem wrong in your test. it should be "8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1" -> "7,8,6,5,4,3,2,1"

Comment: Of course there is a difference between the two. `insertionList[i]` might be modified within the while loop but `temp` does not change.

Comment: Just a guess: perhaps it's because `insertionList[i]` gets over-written in your `while` loop. So preserving the value before the loop starts prevents a bug.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: As others have correctly pointed out, `insertionList[i]` changes in the loop, `temp` does not. Things like this are easily detected using a debugger. Check the linked duplicate to learn how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while(j >= 0 && insertionList[j] > insertionList[i]) {
            insertionList[j + 1] = insertionList[j];
            j--;
        }
```

the wrong is here. insertionList[j + 1] = insertionList[j]

in the first execution, j + 1 = i, and it will change the value of insertionList[i]

and it will effect to your condition.

```
insertionList[j] > insertionList[i]
```

So it should be change to temp variable.

Comment: I still get same result.

Comment: you ask "Just wondering what different between insertionList[i] and temp", i explained it.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that the 'insertionList' gets modified inside the while loop.
When you set the temp variable to 'insertionList[i]' the value of temp remains the same throughout the while loop.

Comment: I used JetBrains, eclipse, and terminal in my mac. all result are same. I didn't get right answer in the code with insertionList[i]

Answer (score 0):

`while(j >= 0 && insertionList[j] > insertionList[i])`
In this line you are comparing with the ith element of `insertionList` and during the iteration in `while` loop `insertionList[j + 1] = insertionList[j];` this code might change the value `insertionList[i]` was holding. But when you are using `temp` variable then for the whole iteration the value for comparison here `insertionList[j] > temp` does not change. That's why you are getting different output.